# Remove a row by key on Google Sheet with gsheets package

Tags: flutter, dart, google-sheets

This is an example code, here i find the row by key. I need something like this, but that delete a row if i know the key. (I don't know the index)

```
import 'package:gsheets/gsheets.dart';

...

Future deleteUser() async {
    final gsheets = GSheets(_credentials);
    final ss = await gsheets.spreadsheet(_spreadsheetId);
    var sheet = ss.worksheetByTitle('game');
    row = await sheet.values.rowByKey("key"); 
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved with this:

```
void deleteUser() async {
    final gsheets = GSheets(_credentials);
    final ss = await gsheets.spreadsheet(_spreadsheetId);
    var sheet = ss.worksheetByTitle('game');
    final lista = await sheet.values.allRows();
    for(var i=0; i<lista.length; i++){
        var riga=lista[i];
        if (riga[0] == dati[0]){           //dati[0] contain the key
        sheet.deleteRow(i+1);
        break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).